# foreach retrieve data in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, foreach, cakephp-2.0

i want to display all recipe data in my view so when i click on  Recipe data here i will get whole array.

i am little confuse over here how can i get  this data in my view part

```
[Recipe] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => test
        [desc] => test
        [makes] => 1
        [created_by] => 1
        [is_deleted] => 0
        [created_date] => 2018-03-14 13:09:43
    )

[RecipeCategory] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [recipe_id] => 1
                [categories_id] => 3
                [created_on] => 2018-03-14 13:17:01
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [category_name] => Kitchen
                        [is_ingredient] => 1
                        [created_by] => 1
                        [is_default] => 1
                        [created_on] => 2018-03-14 09:32:01
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [recipe_id] => 1
                [categories_id] => 7
                [created_on] => 2018-03-14 13:17:01
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 7
                        [category_name] => sfsd
                        [is_ingredient] => 0
                        [created_by] => 1
                        [is_default] => 0
                        [created_on] => 2018-03-14 13:09:43
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [recipe_id] => 1
                [categories_id] => 8
                [created_on] => 2018-03-14 13:17:01
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 8
                        [category_name] => fsdfsdf
                        [is_ingredient] => 0
                        [created_by] => 1
                        [is_default] => 0
                        [created_on] => 2018-03-14 13:09:43
                    )

            )

    )

[RecipeStep] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [recipe_id] => 1
                [desc] => 
                [created_on] => 2018-03-14 13:17:01
                [RecipeIngredient] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [recipe_steps_id] => 2
                                [ingredients_id] => 1042
                                [qty] => 1
                                [unit] => each
                                [preparation] => tr5est
                                [created_on] => 2018-03-14 13:17:01
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

how to retrieve  data and display in view like

Recipe Category : display all category name here

RecipeIngredient : display all Recipe Ingredient name here

Thanks for  your help

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: Normally you can use `$recipe = $this->Recipe->find('all'));` and `$this->set('recipe', $recipe);` in your `RecipesController` to get your data and set it to the view. In your view you can echo it it via `<?= $recipe['name']?>`. How you can access the data of RecipesCategory depends a bit on your Model nesting. See https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations

Comment: ya i know this but  but  record is not in same table so i have to use bind modal query to get this result